# Local Electron solution for basic CRUD operations

Tags: javascript, sql, json, database, electron

I'm mainly a RoR developer, I've never really got into JS, but recently I've been needing to create a desktop application so I've been looking at Electron. 
I've been trying to go over how I can keep this completely local, even having the program write to a text file, or something like a JSON file.

Can anyone suggest how i go about this, I've looked at a few tutorials in how to get Electron started, but all I need is a simple lookup app with the ability to create, delete and edit.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an embedded database. Electron has some built in options available . LocalStorage (without the size limitations you'll find in chrome), WebSql and IndexedDb.

Each of those databases has its advantages. LocalStorage has a very simple API but is quite limited while IndexedDb is very powerful but it has a rather complex API.

I would recommend using some library that abstracts any of this databases.

I personally like [PouchDb](https://pouchdb.com/). Which makes sense if you want synchronization functionality.

I also recommend [Nolan Lawson blog](https://nolanlawson.com/), he writes about databases and JS stuff. [This post](https://nolanlawson.com/2016/02/08/how-to-think-about-databases/) in particular is really helpful. PouchDb uses indexedDb as the default storage layer.

[LocalForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) is another good alternative and also [Dixie.js](http://dexie.org/)

In my case I use Pouchdb with backbone. I replaced `Backbone.sync` method with a PouchDb adapter, this way I ca use Backbone models like I would do with a regular javascript application.

Comment: Hi limoragni, Do you perhaps have any suggestions if I would like to use electron to have local db (i will investigate your points above in a second and I see now PouchDB may have what i need) but also I would like to synchronize date when connection is available with let's call it backup database? Do you think it would be possible in some easy way or rather preparing own synchronization mechanism may be needed here?

Comment: @Lormitto If you want to sync I think PouchDb is your best bet. It's a database designed for that propuse. You can have a CouchDB database online and sync your data to that database with one of the many options PouchDB has for synchronization.